# How to get direct video link from twitter using tweepy

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python

I want to extract the direct video link for a tweet using this:

```
tweet_media = clean_data['extended_entities']['variants'][0]['url']
```

`clean_data` is where the tweet info is stored.

According to the [Twitter documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/data-dictionary/overview/tweet-object), the direct url to a video is under `extended_entities`, and [in this document](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/data-dictionary/overview/extended-entities-object), there should be `'variants'` inside `extended_entities`, and inside that, `url`, where the video link is. However, when using the line of code above, I get a KeyError:

```
Exception has occurred: KeyError
    tweet_media = clean_data['extended_entities']['variants'][0]['url']
KeyError: 'variants'
```

Of course, I'm doing something wrong here, so if someone could please explain to me what exactly I'm doing wrong, and how to fix it, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking at "**Tweet with native video**" [in this document](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/data-dictionary/overview/extended-entities-object#tweet-video) I can see that `variants` is not directly inside `extended_entities` but nested inside an array called `media` and an object called `video_info`.

```py
# Access video info
video_info = clean_data["extended_entities"]["media"][0]["video_info"]

# Get direct video link
tweet_media = video_info["variants"][0]["url"]
```